# Eclipse not responding in windows 8

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I am using eclipse(luna) now it's giving error not responding when I save the file. It's taking more time,how can I fix it.

Comment: In any case, it's strongly advised that you use Eclipse Neon instead. Some work was done in the last years to improve performances, you should take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

This could occur if you have too many files open in Eclipse or you have not restarted your system or eclipse for sometime. Try restarting your system and see if you its fast while working with it.